# Get access token from facebook using graph API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I have created the [page](https://www.facebook.com/AchchaYenbadhuMadamaiyada) in facebook and I would like to get facebook stats daily using [graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api).

I can get access token by using [facebook explorer tools](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) , but it is expired shortly.

I need long live access token to get insights details by using graph API. It would help to get facebook stats daily. If anyone knows it, please share your suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: RTFM: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension

Answer (score 0):

You will need to gather the access token from your user with permission 'manage_pages'.

Then you can use this request

```
GET /oauth/access_token?
grant_type=fb_exchange_token&amp;
client_id={app-id}&amp;
client_secret={app-secret}&amp;
fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

to obtain a long living page access token.
Use this for your statistics.

Answer (score 0):

Read about the tokens here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

1. Get the **user access token** with `manage_pages` permission
2. **Extend** the user access token as explained in here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension
3. Use the above token and get the **page access token** using `/v2.5/{page-id}?fields=access_token`

   The token you  get here wont expire.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens#get-a-long-lived-user-access-token) to get long-lived user access token

```
curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
  client_id=APP-ID&
  client_secret=APP-SECRET&
  fb_exchange_token=SHORT-LIVED-USER-ACCESS-TOKEN"
```